# QProcess write multiple command to the same session in same window

Tags: shell, qt, adb, qprocess

I build an app to send some commands from pc to android phone
it's working great when I send single command but in some processes i need to write multiple commands in the same session

[image]

This is the code I use now

```
QString Adb::cmd(const QString &command)
{
    QProcess P2;
    P2.start(command);
    P2.waitForFinished(-1);
    P2.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    QTextStream reade2(&P2);
    QString line2,line,Out;
    while (reade2.readLineInto(&line2))
        Out.append(line2 +'\n');
    P2.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardError);
    QTextStream reader(&P2);
    while (reader.readLineInto(&line))
        Out.append(line +'\n');
    P2.close();
    return Out.trimmed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `finished` signal to know if a single command is finished. Then you can start another one there.

`connect(&myProcess,SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)),this,SLOT(processFinished()));`

```
void processFinished(){
// if a command A is finished, try B
}
```